# Eventlistener click not changing variable when pressed

Tags: javascript

I'm Building a slideshow event on my website and i was wondering how to change variable `i`

javascipt

```
var list = document.getElementById('list1');
list.addEventListener("click", press());

var slideshow = document.getElementById('slideshow');
var bilder = ['bild1.png','bild2.png','bild3.png'];
var totalpics = mypics.length;
var i = 0;
var a= 0

function press(){
i=0;
}

function loop() {
    if(i > (totalpics - 1)){
    i = 0;  
    }
slideshow.innerHTML = '<img src="bilder/'+bilder[i]+'">';
i++;
loopTimer = setTimeout ('loop()',3000);
}
loop();
```

html

```
<div id="slideshow">

</div>
<li id="list1"></li>
<li id="list2"></li>
<li id="list3"></li>
```

Why is `i` not changing to 0 when i press `li id="list1"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the function itself not the result of its invocation

```
list.addEventListener("click", press);
```

and btw

```
loopTimer = setTimeout (loop, 3000);
```

Comment: Now it will run the loop when clicked and after the time it will go back to zero agian, is it possible to cancle/reset the loop? becouse if you press many times it will actaully speed up the loop.

Comment: Like `function restart() {i=0; loopTimer&&clearTimeout(loopTimer); loop();}` ?